# What about SEO with NodeJS (wo Angular)

Tags: node.js, express, seo, pug

I have a web site (multi page), that give some general information, but also generate information that come from a database (product description....)

The website architecture is done with nodejs, express, bootstrap and jade (mysql)

Is there any issue with SEO ?
I have seen many post about using nodeJS + angularJS, but what if not !

Should I just add to my jade template the basic SEO info (description and keyword) in hard ? or is there something smarter ?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Search engines do not read the serverside code, SEO will be exactly the same as with any other serverside language.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about SEO

Comment: Ok... but (sorry if i'm not aware enough), this is my language that generates the HTML that will be on the client ! How should I do (the good one) to add to my jade template sufficient and well organize information to make the Google bots accepting me ?

Comment: You need to learn general SEO techniques, generally SEO questions go to [webmasters](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/).  If you have a specific question about how to implement a technique in your code, then that can go here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just follow the usual [SEO rules](http://static.googleusercontent.com/media/www.google.com/en//webmasters/docs/search-engine-optimization-starter-guide.pdf) in your Jade (which will be rendered as HTML) and nothing should change. Google is not aware of server-side code so PHP, RoR or NodeJS shouldn't change anything.

Just make sure you organize your routes according to the best practices (the document I linked covers this aspect). That's the only server-side code I can think of that could impact on SEO.